# Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind?

Tags: git, github

**My story:**

I am working on a project and by accident i commited all changes under same commit message to **Github**, but this wasn't the problem, i used

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

and everything solved locally, now i am trying to push that to **Github** again but i got this message always:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dr-coder/Chat-App.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How to return my Github repo to push state again??

Comment: I think the Git history was altered by you locally. You either need to fix the history locally or force push to the remote repo (which is VERY dangerous)

Comment: but the problem is not locally i think, the problem in github, it has one more commit that i need to revert, but i don't know how, i tried from the website but both git and github are new to me

Comment: If you're the only dev who is working on that repo, then you can do a force push which will resolve your issue

Comment: @konekoya Thank you this worked , you can add your answer if you want

Comment: It's okay, I actually not really sure if it would work or not :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you’re the only one working on the repo, you can do a:

```
git-push --force
```

If you’re not, you can revert the old changes using in the following:

```
git checkout -b old-state COMMIT
```

This will create a branch with the commit you want to revert to.

Comment: COMMIT is SHA??

Comment: @CodeEagle yes it is